# Why isn't CSS loading on my django website?

Tags: css, django, cpanel, django-staticfiles

I have managed to upload my django project to a server([www.sb10-89.co.uk](http://www.sb10-89.co.uk) but the css file isn’t working. Even the admin page doesn't look right, again i guess its missing a css page.

The code below is from my settings file.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = 'staticfiles/bands_ratings'
```

See below image for file structure.
[image: file directory]

Connecting css in html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Style.css' %}" >
```

Project level urls file code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('bands_ratings/', include ('bands_ratings.urls')),
    path('',RedirectView.as_view(url='bands_ratings/signup/')),        
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
#urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Looks like the line starting with `<link rel="stylesheet"...` hasn't made it into your HTML.

Comment: Can you see a problem?

Comment: When i look at page source it shows <link rel="stylesheet" href="/staticfiles/Style.css" >

Comment: In that case, you're not looking at the page you linked to above. That has no link: `view-source:https://www.sb10-89.co.uk/bands_ratings/signup/`.

Comment: When you sign up and login in it redirects you to a page where i want the css to appear but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should run `manage.py collectstatic` when going into production (strictly after setting DEBUG-FALSE).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/deployment/